# Laravel post request returns a method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my routes file I have

```
Route::post('/request-rest-password', 'HomeController@requestResetPwd');
```

IN the controller

```
  public function requestResetPwd(Request $request){
      return $request;
  }
```

Now whenever I try post it always throws an error

> "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","file":
>   "/var/www/html/freelancer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",

Where could I be going wrong
Example of a post

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -F "email=test@test.com" -F  ....... 
        "http://localhost:8000/request-reset-pwd"
```

Comment: this will be your link  : http://localhost:8000/request-reset-password

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

Route: `request-rest-password`
POST: `request-reset-pwd`

Comment: thanks ive seen my stupid mistake whick took 1hr debugging

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Lol, these things happen

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('/request-rest-password', 'HomeController@requestResetPwd')->name('post_insert');
```

and your form html should contain route like this ...

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('post_insert')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
  your user fields goes here...
</form>
```